# TkInter Tk() not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have much experience with Python, but I'm just now learning Tkinter and the following code isn't working:

```
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

It spits out the error message
"NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined"

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get a syntax error? Does the program crash? Are you importing it from Tkinter? Are you calling `mainloop()`?

Comment: Oh I just got it I wasn't importing Tkinter :/ Thanks Bryan

Comment: you will get the same error if you inadvertently save your file with the same name as the library you are importing... tkinter in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are simply not importing the tkinter library.

The quick solution is to add `from tkinter import *` to the top of your file.

However, **global imports are generally a bad idea**. I know lots of tkinter tutorials start out this way, but they shouldn't. I recommend doing it this way:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

It requires that you prefix every tkinter command with `tk.`, but it makes your code easier to understand, and easier to maintain over time. If, for example, you decide to import `ttk` (some modern looking tkinter widgets), it is impossible to know if `Button(...)` refers to the ttk button or the tk button if you use global imports. However, `tk.Button(...)` and `ttk.Button(...)` are crystal clear.

Answer (score 3):

The error occurred because the file was named as `tkinter.py` and caused the `tkinter` library import to fail.

Make sure your file name differs.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the problem i was having. I was working up an example of using tkinter, so of course I called it tkinter.  Python can be weird with these types of errors, giving few hints as to the cause.